# Store the return array into new variable

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I get a return array from controller

controller

```
$data['rec'] = $this->Hire_model->get_rec();
```

and get this data

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["UserID"]=> int(37) } [1]=> array(1) { ["UserID"]=> int(52) } }
```

I want to check if the session I have has the same value in that return data or not. I don't know how to do it in JQuery. I try this but it doesn't work.

```
var recruiter = [];        
$.each(<?php echo $rec;?>,function(i) {
   recruiter.push(<?php echo $rec[i]['UserID']; ?>);
});
```

I try to save the return data into new array variable then check it if its has the same value with the session. But I always get error "Array to string conversion" to save it into new variable. Anyone can help me with this?? Any help will be appreciate

Thank You

Comment: `<?php echo $rec;?>` You cannot `echo` an array, because php cannot know how to interpret it as a string. That's where the error is coming from. Why are you doing this in jQuery instead of php?

Comment: I want to differentiate the view based on that data, so, I do it in jquery. what should I do then?

Comment: I'm completely confused. You can differentiate the view in php as well. Why would you suddenly switch technologies and use jQuery to iterate a php array? Do the comparison in the controller and send your view a simple boolean switch to decide what to show.

Comment: You're right, ohh thank you to give me an idea :)

Comment: Using php, run your array through a foreach() loop and check to see if the values are in the array using in_array().